# Show decimal places in percentage and decimal point only if needed

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to set a Data format in POI so that it will show values like this:

> 12.5%
>   12.75% 15%

So, it should only show the decimal point if needed and then only show the fractional values if needed.

I have it partially working using this format:

`stylePercentage.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("#.##%"));`

However, this prints 15% like:

> 15.%

From the research I've been doing, I'm not sure if what I am trying is possible.

Is there a way to alter the data formatter to only show the decimal point if it is needed?

Comment: @pnuts, I can present this as an option, I don't get to make the end decision on it.. so there is a way to make it print just 15 (for whole number) and 12.5 (for fractional)?, what would be the format for this to have it not print the decimal unless needed? Thanks!

Comment: do you actually need the % symbol in the cell or is it just for show.

Comment: I believe it is needed, but not my call in the end

Answer (score 2):

Check out [BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html).
[HSSFDataFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataFormat.html) has a method that can retrieve these for you.

```
workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("0.00%"));
```

Comment: This is how I had it originally, then it would always print as 15.00%. I want it to print like 15% if there are no fractional values and like 12.5% if there are...